# What's this green vegetable with no leaves used in Cantonese cuisine?

Tags: vegetables

I read [pp 13-14 of Tang Court's menu](http://www.langhamhotels.com/en/the-langham/hong-kong/dining/tang-court/) but they don't stipulate [this vegetable](https://www.openrice.com/en/hongkong/p-tang-court-p1653722)'s name.

[image]

Comment: The image looks similar to those in this question: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/103548/is-thicker-gai-lan-less-chewable-and-piercable

Answer (score 2):

That appears to be [gai lan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gai_lan), or a closely related Chinese brassica like [yu choy](https://www.melissas.com/Yu-Choy-Sum-p/1102.htm), with the leaves removed.  So just the stems.

I haven't seen (or found) a recipe for just the stems in broth, but it makes a certain amount of sense; the leaves cook much faster than the thick stems, so sometimes just the leaves are used for stir-fry.  Then you can do this with the stems.

Answer (score -2):

Probably leeks. Almost all Asian meals use them. Similar to onions or cabbage

[image]!